# :hover effects not working

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm using FoundationPress https://foundationpress.olefredrik.com/ 
to make a site. I'm trying to toggle the display of a div by hovering on another div. Here is the styling:

```
.test_div {
background-color:blue;
height:50px;
display:none;
}

.test_button {
width:100px;
height:50px;
background-color:blue;
cursor:pointer;
}

.test_button:hover {
background-color:green;
}

.test_button:hover .test_div {
background-color: red;
display:block;
}
```

And here is the html:

```
<div class='test_button'>Hover to change test_div</div>
<div class='test_div'>I should be displayed</div>
```

It just won't work. 
Thanks.

Comment: @DeneaNovac That's not true. You can use the general or immediate sibling selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sibling css selector `~`.
Note that the two elements should be siblings (have the same parent) And the first should appear before the second in the DOM tree.

```css
.test_div {
background-color:blue;
height:50px;
display:none;
}

.test_button {
width:100px;
height:50px;
background-color:blue;
cursor:pointer;
}

.test_button:hover {
background-color:green;
}

.test_button:hover ~ .test_div {
background-color: red;
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class='test_button'>Hover to change test_div</div>
<div class='test_div'>I should be displayed</div>
```

Comment: @Gordog, a voteup on the answer will also be appreciated :)

Comment: @gordog, you can click on the arrow-up on the left of the answer to vote it.

Answer (score 1):

There's just a very small thing missing. Your selector is wrong. It should be:

```
.test_button:hover + .test_div {
   background-color: red;
   display:block;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8rtjzmw6/

What you need is a so called *Adjacent sibling selector*, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors
it allows you to select the next element.

with the selector `.test_button:hover .test_div`  you selected it like `test_div` would be a child of `test_button`

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a plus in your statement

nonte this only works if the element is the next sibling

```css
.test_div {
background-color:blue;
height:50px;
display:none;
}

.test_button {
width:100px;
height:50px;
background-color:blue;
cursor:pointer;
}

.test_button:hover {
background-color:green;
}

.test_button:hover + .test_div {
background-color: red;
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class='test_button'>Hover to change test_div</div>
<div class='test_div'>I should be displayed</div>
```